# How to use the compose key in Qt apps?

Tags: keyboard, input, qt

In elementary OS 0.4 Loki the compose key work in the stock applications but not in the Qt/KDE ones (such as Anki). Is there a way so that the input method configured in *System Settings* can be used in Qt/KDE apps as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the package `ibus-qt4`.

Comment: I have been banging my head against a wall trying to get a custom ibus layout to work.. everything works except the typing.. so I went to try "compose" key.. and read lots on how to do it..   I installed ibus-qt4 and everything worked.. THANKS A MILLION!